# Javascript scroll and iphone / ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, television, channel

I'm making a mobile version of my website (programmetv.net) and i have a problem with javascript scroll event who not work on ipad same on a pc.

You can see my mobile version on http://www.programmetv.net/ipad/index.php?date=20130210

If you test with a pc, the channels stay in the left of the screen, but if you test with an ipad (or iphone), you can see my javascript do not work correctly. The channels become invisible and if you stop to scroll they become visible.

There is my javascript to to this :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.onscroll = scrollIt;
    function scrollIt() {
        var node = document.getElementById("chaines");
        var XX = 0;
        var YY = 0;
        var posit = (window.pageXOffset < (XX-YY)) 
            ? XX : window.pageXOffset + YY;
        node.style.left = posit + "px";
    }
</script>
```

I would like help to make ipad version of my javascript who work like on a pc (firefox).

Comment: Did you tried using touchmove event?